# i am trying to make a disney plus clone but i am having a error which says

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux

./src/app/store.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../features/movie/movieSlice' in 'C:\Users\user\diseny-plus-clone\src\app'

so please tell me how to rectify this problem

**this  is the code of the file having error**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import counterReducer from "../features/counter/counterSlice";
import movieReducer from "../features/movie/movieSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    movie: movieReducer,
  },
});
```

**next is the code of the file through which i have imported**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  movies: [],
};

const movieSlice = createSlice({
  name: "movie",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setMovies: (state, action) => {
      state.movies = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setMovies } = movieSlice.actions;

export const selectMovies = (state) => state.movie.movies;

export default movieSlice.reducer();
```

please help me out

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your directory structure ?

Comment: Is the path of `movieSlice.js` the following?  `C:\Users\user\diseny-plus-clone\src\features\movie\movieSlice.js`

Comment: We need to see the project structure and don't forget to change this line export default movieSlice.reducer(); to export default movieSlice.reducer;

Comment: https://github.com/pradyumn123234/diseny-plus-clone.git
this is my whole code

Comment: yes taxel its the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to access to movieSlice file is wrong, the correct path is  `../features/counter/movie/movieSlice`.

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import counterReducer from "../features/counter/counterSlice";
import movieReducer from "../features/counter/movie/movieSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    movie: movieReducer,
  },
});
```

Comment: thanks bro for your help